# Router.use deprecated in iron router 1.0?

Tags: meteor, connect, iron-router

I attempt the following to no avail:

```
Router.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log("my handler workzz");
    this.next();
}, {where: "server"});
```

Although per [The Iron Router Docs](http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#server-middleware-and-connect), this is perfectly valid syntax. What is the correct way to add a connect middleware ?

I'd be open to non-connect options as well. What I really want to do is to md5 an incoming request, and if that request issues a redirect, append the md5 as a query parameter to that redirect. For this I believe I'll need access to the incoming request AND the response, and thus a simple before hook would probably not work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Router.use` is deprecated and needs to be removed per the notes in [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/928).

A combination of `onBeforeAction` and `onAfterAction`, possibly rolled up in a plugin, seems like the path forward.